# I need to keep two only one digit after decimal point number in perl

Tags: perl, cgi, perl-module

Eg : 4.5674 = > 4.6

I have tried below code in CGI. But I not able to get the output.

```
use Math::Round;
use Math::Round qw(:all);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $rounded = nearest(.1, 4.65);
print $rounded;
```

below error it is displaying

```
Illegal character \015 (carriage return) at //ms/dist/perl5/PROJ/Math-Round/0.06/lib/perl5/Math/Round.pm line 1.
(Maybe you didn't strip carriage returns after a network transfer?)
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ......
```

Please help to get the output of this one.

Comment: It is telling you the problem.  The problem is in `Round.pm` -- it seems to have CRLF line endings.

Comment: Thanks Devnull! How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: A simple web search should do it: (1) _remove cr from file_, (2) _crlf to lf_, (3) _remove carriage return_, ...

Comment: @devnull: Please post your comment as an answer if you think it resolves the question.

Comment: @Vasanth: The code you have posted correctly prints `4.7`. What is your real problem?

Comment: use `%.2f` to take two decimals

Comment: @Biridin now its working fine. I have executed wrongly.

Perl test.cgi - > ./test.pl

I think execution is the problem..

Answer (score 2):

About rounding numbers, use sprintf function

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $n = 4.5674;

print sprintf('%.02f',$n);
```

Next to convert windows line endings to Unix line ending, on a *nix machine use the following command

```
$ dos2unix my_program_file.pl
```

Comment: `dos2unix` isn't standard on a lot of UNIX installs. Debian says `bash: dos2unix: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the original script was written on Windows and is now being used on UNIX with the wrong line endings (CR LF instead of LF).

To replace CR LF (Windows line endings) with LF (UNIX line endings), run the file through this regex:

```
s/\012\015/\n/g;
```

A simple perl file to do this would be:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<>) {
    $_ =~ s/\012\015/\n/g;
    print $_;
}
```

You'd run this as follows:

```
$ perl fixlineendings.pl oldfile.pl > newfile.pl
```